# How to add a user to a Cognito User Pool Group from AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to add a user a to cognito user pool group from a lambda that gets triggered post confirmation. This is the code for that lambda:

```js
    export async function postAuth(event, context, callback) {
      var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
      var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});
  
      var params = {
        GroupName: process.env.S3_GROUP_NAME,
        UserPoolId: event.userPoolId,
        Username: event.userName
      };

      cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminAddUserToGroup(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log("Error");
        else     console.log("Success");
      });
  
      console.log("Executed.");

      context.succeed(event);

    }
```

I know for a fact that this lambda gets triggered because the I can see "executed" gets logged on CloudWatch. However, the call to `adminAddUserToGroup` doesn't seem to go through at all as neither the error message nor the success message get logged.

My reason for trying to do this is so that I can grant groups different roles to access backend resources. For instance I could have a group `Admin` with the role `CanWriteToS3` and a group `Customer` with the role `CanReadFromS3` and add or remove users from groups as needed.

I suspect one of the issues with this lambda is that it lacks the correct permissions to add and remove users from a group.

This is the role attached to the lambda:

```yaml
    GroupManagementRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: GroupManagementRole
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Principal:
                Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: "GroupManagementPolicy"
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - logs:CreateLogGroup
                    - logs:CreateLogStream
                    - logs:PutLogEvents
                  Resource: 
                    - 'Fn::Join':
                      - ':'
                      -
                        - 'arn:aws:logs'
                        - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
                        - Ref: 'AWS::AccountId'
                        - 'log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*:*'
                - Effect: "Allow"
                  Action: ["cognito-idp:AdminAddUserToGroup", "cognito-idp:AdminRemoveUserFromGroup"]
                  Resource:
                    Fn::Join:
                       - ""
                       - - "arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:userpool/us-east-1_XXXXXXX/*"
```

I'm not sure whether I should be using the cognito user pool's arn for the resource but I've searched online and I cannot find any documentation on cognito user pool groups ARNs.

Whatever the problem is, I can't diagnose it since my call to `adminAddUserToGroup` doesn't seem to go through at all.

Comment: Hey @MrD, I have an exact need as yours (using custom roles using groups). It looks pretty straight forward to me, but i read somewhere that `adminAddUserToGroup` function requires the AWS Account credentials, but I don't see a way to pass it. Is there no need to pass AWS Credentials to the service provider if Lambda has the proper IAM Roles assigned to it?

Comment: [`adminAddUserToGroup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminAddUserToGroup-property) doesn't take any account credentials afaik, I managed to get this working as it is, but I ran into a different problem later on which is that in order to add/remove users from you need the cognito username (as opposed to the identity pool id). The username is available when a lambda gets triggered by cognito but say for s3 events it is not.

Comment: Ah I see. I was able to make it work using a slightly modified version of your code. I set the Lambda function to be triggered by "Post Verification" and it was able to successfully add the user to the appropriate group. Now I am trying to find out a way to pass the appropriate group name from my app through cognito user custom attributes so that i don't hard code it in the function. I guess to my original question, I was confused by reading various posts on AWS forums and elsewhere but it worked as is as you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to store the group name on a custom attribute? If you just want to avoid hardcoding the group name just use an environment variable. It should be super simple to setup, especially if you are using serverless framework or something.

Comment: I have 3 different type of users that can sign up in our app and 3 corresponding groups. The type of user (or group) is determined by the way the user is signing up in our app. Based on the type of user I will assign the custom attribute to the new user at the time of sign up from within the app and then ultimately use that attribute to deduce the group name in the Lambda function. Environment variable is fine, but I would still need a way to tell my lambda function about which user goes where. Not sure if there is any other better way though.\

Comment: I was under the impression that users can edit their own custom attributes (altho don't quote me on this). The only other alternative I can think of is to have separate user pools for each type of user.

Comment: Well, some of the default custom attributes can definitely be added by the user if you want them to, but i added my own custom attributes like "user_permission" while creating the user Pool. and then I pass the value of user_permission inside of the parameters object (along with others) while invoking the `SignUp()` method. See this for more on how to pass custom attributes - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/aws-amplify-adds-support-for-custom-attributes-in-amazon-cognito-user-pools/

Comment: Yep, I mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569644/is-it-safe-to-authenticate-a-cognito-user-through-api-gateway-to-lambda-using-a). You need to make sure you make your custom attribute writable from the frontend.

Comment: Got it, but I am not actually using the claim support that comes with identity pool, I actually need the attributes to be Mutable and yes, I did mark them as Mutable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main issue is that you are defining your function as an Async.
If you define async function, you shouldn't use callback in the body.

Please make sure you use the promise versions in your function body.

```
try {
    await cognitoISP.adminAddUserToGroup(params).promise();
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

Like this

Comment: changing the function from async to normal fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks fine except Resource.

You need to give Userpool in following format:
arn:aws:cognito-idp:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:userpool/USER_POOL_ID

I am doing same thing but use Resource: *.

CHeck if Resource: * works or not. That way you will be able to confirm the problem area.

Comment: Changing Resource to "*" seems to have no effect. Still no logs on cloudwatch for success or failure either.